# devise override controller and views and use different views for different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have two different devise models 'Admin' and 'Businesses' and i am overriding the registration and sessions controller for both of the models ,and i have different views of both the models inside folder admins and businesses . but after overriding the controller customize views are not rendering . how can i render different views of both models. My code looks like as follows:

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :businesses , controllers: {sessions: "business_sessions",registrations: 'business_registrations'}
  devise_for :admins , controllers: {sessions: "owner_sessions" }
```

**owner_sessions_controller.rb**

```
class OwnerSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController



  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    session[:team_id] = resource.id
    if !session[:return_to].blank?
      redirect_to session[:return_to]
      session[:return_to] = nil
    else
      redirect_to owner_dash_board_path
    end

  end

end
```

I have done >>>`config.scoped_views = true`

for views i have different folders for admins and business .

So how can i use customize views for controller actions while overriding the controller.

Comment: on second thought... that might not be what you're after. You already have your views in a folder yes? but it's just not finding them due to the new naming? Have you put the views into the same place that you'd have the devise views if you actually had those resources?

Comment: The Devise documentation seems to think it's relatively simple to `scope` your views - are you sure you put them into the correct folders?

Comment: i think my folder structure is fine .. i have model business , views folder name businesses ,registration controller name is business_registrations_Controller.rb

Comment: Have you restarted your server after changing `config.scoped_views = true`?

Comment: yes multiple times ..but still i am getting the default form ..this is case when i override my controller..